# Tengo este mensaje de error cada que inicio alguno de mis proyectos, Cómo lo resuelvo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

Resulta que quería actualizar material skin, asi que entre al administrador de paquetes(*NugetPackageManagment*) y como no daba ningún resultado solo lo cerré y desde ahí es que me lanza el error al iniciar cualquier proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ver https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3419#issuecomment-246733068 y https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3419#issuecomment-289657942

Comment: @aloMalbarez muchos usuarios vienen a Stack Overflow en español porque tienen problemas con el inglés (no digo que éste sea el caso de OP). Dejar un comentario con enlaces a páginas en inglés puede no ser de ayuda para la persona que pregunta. Deberías escribir una respuesta en español referenciando los enlaces en inglés. Eso será de más ayuda para la persona que pregunta y otros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema en el futuro (que tendrá pregunta y respuesta en una sola página en lugar de tener que ir siguiendo enlaces, además de que los comentarios no se indexan y pueden perderse).

Answer (score 1):

Yo también estoy aprendiendo y creo que [esto podría ayudarte](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24733/visual-studio-nuget-package-manager-ignores-nugetc.html).

Según ese problema, lo que se hizo para solucionarlo fue mover `nuget.config` a la carpetas de Solutions (como indica [Iris Sakura en su comentario](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/29372/view.html)).

Comment: La parte esencial de la página enlazada está en la respuesta: "_lo que se hizo para solucionarlo fue mover nuget.config a la carpetas de Solutions_"